# Non-binding constraints with positive shadow prices (matlab)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

The output of fmincon indicates positive shadow price for linear constraints, although the corresponding constraints are not binding. What could be wrong mathematically? I've checked the code but couldn't find any mistake.

Comment: That really shouldn't happen. I think the error must be in the code...

Comment: @Shane, it is due to the high tolerance limits, the iteration stops without finding the local minimum.